# Checkbox bind/unbind logic

Tags: javascript, html, css, checkbox

Hi i have a situation where the binding for a table containing checkbox is done at the header checkbox

i.e when u select the header check all table rows get selected .

but due to this the problem comes when i unselect an row from the table the header chekcbox should get unselected which is not happening

and suppose i uncheck the header checkbox entire table row will be unchecked coz of the binding issue

please suggest some logic to solve it

I tried retrieving the table row checkbox value and again rendering it but it's a memory constraint.

Thanks in advance

Comment: im using javascript for developing i t

Comment: Please post your code.

Comment: Well logic would be something like this: on your single row checkbox click listener have a piece of code that checks if the row has been unchecked. If at least one row has been unchecked then in that case the header checkbox has to uncheck as well. You could even loop through all of the rows when clicking and test if all of the rows have been checked, and in that case set the head checkbox to 'checked' state.

Comment: but the problem with this logic is my binding is on the header  checkbox if i unselect the header chekbox entire table row will be unselected

Answer (score 0):

**HTML**

```
<input type="checkbox" id="header" />
<li>
    <input type="checkbox" class="sub" />
</li>
<li>
    <input type="checkbox" class="sub" />
</li>
<li>
    <input type="checkbox" class="sub" />
</li>
```

**JS**

```
var headCheckbox = document.getElementById('header');
var subCheckbox = document.getElementsByClassName('sub');

headCheckbox.addEventListener('change', function (e) {
    for (var i = 0; i < subCheckbox.length; i++) {
        subCheckbox[i].checked = (this.checked ?  true : false);
    }
});

for (var i = 0; i < subCheckbox.length; i++) {
    subCheckbox[i].addEventListener('change', function (e) {
        if (!this.checked) {
            headCheckbox.checked = false;
        } else {
            var checked = 0;
            for (var i = 0; i < subCheckbox.length; i++) {
                if (subCheckbox[i].checked) checked++;
            }
            if (checked == subCheckbox.length) headCheckbox.checked = true;
        }
    });
}
```

[DEMO](http://fiddle.jshell.net/Pisi2012/J28xZ/)

Comment: the above code doesnt select the header checkbox when all the table row are selected...

Comment: Ah, ok. Now it does ;-)

Comment: Thanks alexP your solution works but i need to change my entire binding :(

Answer (score 0):

You may do like below to
1. Select all checkbox on selecting header checkbox.
2. UnSelect header checkbox on unselecting any child checkbox.
3. Select header checkbox on selecting all child checkbox.

**JavaScript :**

```
function selectAll(source) 
{
    var checkboxes = document.getElementsByName('foo');
    for(var i=0, n=checkboxes.length;i<n;i++) {
        checkboxes[i].checked = source.checked;
    }
}  

function selectChk(src)
{
    var isAllChecked = true;
    var headerChk = document.getElementsByName('headerChk');
    if(!src.checked){
        headerChk[0].checked = false;
    }
    else{
        var checkboxes = document.getElementsByName('foo');
         for(var i=0, n=checkboxes.length;i<n;i++) {
               if(!checkboxes[i].checked)
                    isAllChecked = false;
               }
          if(isAllChecked)
             headerChk[0].checked = true;
     }
}
```

**HTML :**

```
<input type="checkbox" onClick="selectAll(this)" name="headerChk" /> Select All<br/>

<input type="checkbox" name="foo" value="bar1" onClick="selectChk(this)"> Bar 1<br/>
<input type="checkbox" name="foo" value="bar2" onClick="selectChk(this)"> Bar 2<br/>
<input type="checkbox" name="foo" value="bar3" onClick="selectChk(this)"> Bar 3<br/>
<input type="checkbox" name="foo" value="bar4" onClick="selectChk(this)"> Bar 4<br/>
```